# Cannot program Mega2560 using Atmel Studio 6.2 and avrdude

Tags: arduino-mega, avrdude, atmel-studio, avr-gcc

So I will admit that I am a noob to Arduino. I have some experience programming microcontrollers, and that was back in the day (about 4 years ago - such as the Freescale 68HC12) so up until this point I thought I was experienced enough to get this Arduino Mega2560 rocking with AVR C using Atmel Studio and avrdude by lunch...

Wrong.

I believe I'm getting held up at what's possible...

**What I want to accomplish:** Write and compile a program in AVR C within Atmel studio. Use the hex file that was built and download that to the Mega. (Keep in mind I was planning on using USB and Arduino as my programmer between PC and ATMega2560 as per this gentleman's example... https://balau82.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/programming-arduino-uno-in-pure-c/ -- however, I was not using his code and he was compiling using avr-gcc...)

**Question:** Is this possible?

Using avrdude when attempting to write the file I get this message... (and my blinking LED goes dark for a few seconds before returning to normal operation)

[image: avrdude error]

When I searched the internet for this issue it was never related to avrdude, but rather a communications issue. I've verified my bootloader is still ok (uploaded other sketches with no issues).

It's certain that I am missing something minor, but this is my first day using Arduino so go easy on me!

Thanks

Comment: try `-c wiring` instead of `-c arduino`. Thats what the IDE uses when uploading to a mega.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that and I get - avrdude: Can't find programmer id "wiring"

Comment: Ok so I've got it to the point of actually uploading to the Mega... and that happened using this line - avrdude -F -V -c wiring -p m2560 -P COM3 -b 115200 -D -U flash:w:tmp\BlinkLED.hex:i but unfortunately I'm getting no blinking! But I think that it's a code/ports pin thing. Thanks for the help guys!